# How to bind a command in XAML/WPF ListBox Drop event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, listbox

I want to do something like this:

```
<ListView PreviewDrop="{Binding TestCommand}">
```

( of course I know its wrong but it shows the idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the InvokeCommandAction with an EventTrigger. See [this link](http://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/2010/10/19/Invoking-commands-from-events-using-the-InvokeCommandAction-behavior.aspx).